# MKMapView double tap

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Following is my code; I am not getting didDoubleTapMap fired.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(didDoubleTapMap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[mkMapView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapOnMap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

[mkMapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: Did you try to implement the gesture delegate? return YES on 'shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer'?

Comment: I was using shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer returning YES,

however wasn't setting delegate 
doubleTap.delegate = self;
singleTap.delegate = self;

So shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer was not getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was missing was,

```
doubleTap.delegate = self;
singleTap.delegate = self;
```

Also don't forget to implement:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```